# Zoom Magnification: Zoom in on Zoom camera feed

Tags: windows-10, zoom, zoom-meeting

On the Zoom Client application, I would like to alter the video feed that I am sending to other people. I would like to zoom in, to magnify the video feed that they are receiving of me. How do I magnify what my camera is sending them? I do not need to magnify what I am receiving, only what I am sending to them.

Comment: If Zoom does not provide a method to adjust the camera, this more than likely, is not a feature of Zoom at this time.

Comment: Zoom does not have a "zoom" function. It will depend on your camera, or setup, being able to offer that function.

Comment: It may also be possible with an external program which takes the feed from your webcam, modifies it in some way, and provides output to Zoom as a virtual camera. For example, OBS Studio may fit the bill. But I'm not familiar with the program, so this is a suggestion, not an answer.